# Rental Property - have someone look for you

Tags: rental-property

My issue is that I live in a city where good rental properties are gone within the first couple hours of being posted... and I'm working **all the time**.

Can I pay someone to check everywhere, check out the place in person and quickly get an application in so you are first in line?

(beyond a realtor who seems to only sell you the houses that they have been paid to rent out and ignore 3rd party house listings?)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a *rental broker*.

Answer (score 1):

Many real estate agents will assist with an apartment hunt, for a suitable fee. In a hot market that may be worth the money. Then again, my best finds were always through co-workers, after the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sounds like an interesting concept for a business, potentially! (grin)

You know, depending on where you live and how big the market is, you might see if there's a local "concierge" service.  These are companies that will act like personal shoppers/assistants for you in all kinds of ways.  I can't speak to the quality of their services or the pricing they use, but it would be a great place to start.

I'm sure you can find listings of them on the web.